# Can I control how many loops in a ES6 forEach loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have created a simple api call using XMLHttpRequest

I have the json back and displaying it within a ES6 forEach loop.

The returning data has 100 items but I only want to show the first 10

Can I use the ES6 forEach loop like a for loop like

```
for(let i=0; i<10; i++)
```

to loop 10 times.

I have an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/m3u6L4w2/)

Comment: The answer below should do it, but if I might add, es6 forEach has a huge performance penalty compared to a `for` loop.  https://jsperf.com/for-vs-forin-vs-forof-vs-foreach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `slice()` to get required part of array and then use `forEach`. Considering your variable name is `array` you can do like below.

```
array.slice(0,10).forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have checked your fiddle and edited that you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eupvmgz7/)

```
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach((post, i) => {
    if(i >= 10){
    return;
    }else{
       console.log(post)
    }

    });
  } else {
    //your stuff...
  }
};

request.send();
```